# runtime folder with dotnet core application

Tags: .net-core

If I create a net core 2 console app and get it to reference another project e.g. MyLibrary.csproj
This (MyLibrary.csproj) is a net core class library

If I run `dotnet publish -c release --output test1`
then in the output folder their is a runtime folder present

I have not found anywhere that describes this folders purpose.
Any one have a link?

Also do I need to copy this as part of my deployment?

The example I have has a reference to `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` which is present in the root publish folder(test1) so why does it need to  get it from the runtime folder when I try to run via `dotnet my.dll`?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a [self contained deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd).

Comment: I believe with dotnet publish the default is not self contained

Comment: self contained requires a RID(Runtime IDentifier) which I am not specifing

Comment: Sure. I'm just as confused as you are by the tooling producing what looks like a self contained deployment

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm seeing the same issue. Seems to be producing a SCD even though I have not asked for that. Driving me crazy.

Answer (score -2):

From the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x)

> `dotnet publish` - Packs the application and its dependencies into a folder for deployment to a hosting system.

Comment: The example I have has System.Data.SqlClient.dll in the root folder and also in the runtime folder where it looks for it at runtime. So why is it then in the root folder via publish

Comment: Also there is no mention or explanation of the runtime folder in the docs